# How to inject Scala variable into html attribute (String) in Scala template HTML

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

Let me explain my requirement. Currently we are using Scala template which has some html code and Scala attributes.

Example *test.scala.html*

```
@(hostName: String, token: String, protocol: String, supportEmail: String)
@import helper._
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
<table>
<tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="color: #626262;">                
                <p style="font-size:14px;">
                    <br/>
                    Our app will let you access your company intranet.<br/><br/>
                    Your activation code is <b>@token</b><br/><br/>

                    If you have any questions, please contact our <a href="mailto:@supportEmail">support team</a> anytime.
                    <br/><br/>
                    Best regards,<br/>
                       The Support Team
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

If you see the above code `@token` and `@supportEmail` is dynamic we are passing to Scala.

Till now looks good. The requirement changes, the customer now wants us to read the content from the database. They want to save the actual html content (*table ... end of table*).

So I took the code and stored it in a database column. I am able to pass this content to my view function by using `@Html`.

Now my new Scala view function looks like the following:

```
@(hostName: String, token:String, protocol: String, supportEmail: String, content: String)
@import helper._
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
 @Html(content)
```

Bu I am not able pass `@token` and `@supportEmail` dynamically. It is treated as a plain string. After rendering it looks like the following :

> Our app will let you access your company intranet, files and SaaS services from your device.
>
> Your activation code is @token
>
> If you have any questions, please contact our support team @supportEmail anytime.
>
> Best regards,
>      The support Team

Can anyone explain me whats wrong with `@Html`, can I parse the dynamic content or not. If not is there any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html` function allows you to insert a fragment of HTML from a variable without escaping special characters like `<` or `>`. However, it works only with static HTML and unfortunately doesn't parse additional Scala code inside it.

In your case, the easiest way to achieve your requirements is to prepare the content in your controller before passing it to the view. Code in controller's method would look more or less like this:

```
public Result showContent() {
    //fetching all your data here
    content = content.replace("@token", token);
    content = content.replace("@supportEmail", supportEmail);
    return ok(views.html.test.render(hostName, protocol, content));
}
```

Basically, you aren't forced to use Twirl placeholders inside the table content. The decision how to mark replaceable parameters in the content is up to you. Just make sure that `replace` calls matches you patterns.

I assumed that `token` and `supportEmail` aren't used in other places of the view, hence I removed them from the header of the view.

```
@(hostName: String, protocol: String, content: String)
```

Simple solutions are usually the best solutions :)

Comment: Even I thought of the same solution but want to check if i can any other alternative with Scala where I can pass dynamic params. For now I started implementation with solution you suggested